# ¿Como generar consulta join adecuada que me traiga datos de dos tablas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy presentando inconvenientes para al momento de mostrar los datos que requiero. Actualmente tengo dos tablas que están relacionada de la siguiente manera:

```
Peliculas    imagenes_peliculas
-id     <--> -pelicula_id
-nombre      -urlimg
-descripcion
```

por medio de id tengo esa relación el caso es que al momento de generar la consulta con leftjoin que es la que me da el resultado más cercano aún así no es lo que quiero.

**El controller**

```
public function ShowAllPeliculas(){
  $list_peliculas = DB::table('peliculas')
      ->leftJoin('imagenes_peliculas', 'peliculas.id', '=', 'imagenes_peliculas.pelicula_id')
      ->get();

  dd($list_peliculas);
  // return view('opciones.reporte')->with(['listado'=>$list_peliculas]);
}
```

esto me muestra algo como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento solo tengo 50 registros pero esta consulta me genera duplicado de datos osea una película que tiene 2 o mas imágenes se repite ese mismo número de imágenes que tenga, el caso del registro que desglosé en la imagen adjunta

lo ideal y por lo que desatrazaría ya que llevo 4 hora intentando hacerlo es que el resultado sea algo así

```
 +"id": 28
  +"codigo": "25550"
  +"nombre": "Expanded reciprocal algorithm"
  +"descripcion": "Et nostrum dolores eligendi. Assumenda maiores recusandae facere quae et doloribus totam omnis. Et doloremque est et consequuntur sunt quod dicta. Et in ut offi ▶"
  +"created_at": "2018-04-12 06:32:48"
  +"updated_at": "2018-04-12 06:32:48"
  +"pelicula_id": 5
  +"urlimg": array:3 [▼
     0 => "1523514768_20728326_1629879290375693_7772596140945660817_n.jpg"
     1 => "1523514768_20728326_162985660817_n.jpg"
     2 => "1523514768_6140945660817_n.jpg"
  ]

}
```

Agradezco su atención espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes la relación uno a muchos creada con Eloquent, bastaría hacer esto:

```
$list_peliculas = Pelicula::with('imagenes')->get();
```

y luego accedes así a las imágenes después de iterar la lista de películas:  `$pelicula->imagenes`

La relación desde el modelo Pelicula sería algo así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pelicula extends Model
{
    public function imagenes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Imagen');
    }
}
```

y en Imagen sería:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Imagen extends Model
{
    public function pelicula()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pelicula');
    }
}
```

Revisa la documentación de las relaciones: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Hice todo correcto pero manda este error 
[Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'imagenes_peliculas.peliculas_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `imagenes_peliculas` where `imagenes_peliculas`.`peliculas_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50))]

No se que puede estar fallando

Comment: ¿Seguro que escribiste `pelicula` en singular en el nombre del método?

Comment: Está en singular he revisado cada cosa pero en realidad no se donde puede estar el fallo tendrá algo que ver como están las llaves foráneas o algo.

Comment: El nombre del modelo debe estar en singular Pelicula

Comment: Aunque no se llame Pelicula ?

Comment: Ok, Bueno cambie todo a singular el archivo del model Peliculas.php quedo y el llamado en todas partes de la clase instancia y todo, y se resolvió el error, ahora si me muestra pero como hago para que me traiga lo que quiero? debo realizar el lefth join como antes?

Comment: No, en la primera parte está explicado todo

Comment: Analizando todo lo que me devuelve me aparece al parecer esos items aquí
#relations: array:1 [▼
        "imagenes" => Collection {#306 ▼
          #items: array:9 [▼]
en este caso 9 imgs como accedo a ellas y poderlas mostrar en el foreach?

Comment: Iterando la colección con un foreach

Comment: Listo muchas gracias por tu tiempo, he resuelto este problemita. Saludos